# Javascript/JQuery/CSS Print - How to specify the shrink percentage in print preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing

In the print preview page, I'd like to specify the scale to say 60% instead to "shrink to fit" in code.

Is there any way to control this setting using JQuery/Javascript or CSS?

Comment: I'm almost positive the answer is "no". You have limited control over features outside of the DOM.